# How to add custom validator to Validators?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I wanna add a custom validator to Validators class, like this:

```
Validators.my_lovely_validator = function() {
  ...
}
```

If I do this the TSC says "Property 'my_lovely_validator' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'"

So, how do you add a custom validator to Validators class?

This is a technical question

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: @AT82, I want to store my validators in Validators

Comment: @lucifer63 `my_lovely_validator` is object property of Validators ? if Yes then You can do like this `Validators['my_lovely_validators'] = function() { }`

Comment: Sure I can, but TSC won't like it anyway

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to extend the `Validators` class type definition. I might suggest nudging your search in that direction.

Comment: @stealththeninja, Yeah, I tried to search something like "typescript extend class", but found only solutions like creating a new class that extends existing class. This is not what needed, I mean adding a property to an existing class, specifically Validators